# Sending Data over Ethernet UDP via lwIP Problem

Tags: c, embedded, udp, lwip

I am trying to send messages using the `lwIP` library by UDP. I am using a TMS570LS3137 microprocessor. Since it is complicated to manage including's of `lwIP` I am using [this example project](https://git.ti.com/cgit/hercules_examples/hercules_examples/tree/Application/LwIP/v00.04.00/TMS570LS31x/Build-TMS570LS31x) by varying `sys_main.c`.

After I build the code below and debug, my while loop works but I don't see any UDP message when I try to see the output by WireShark.

What might be the problem here?

```
//version1
#include "lwip/udp.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h> // For strlen
#include "lwip/init.h" // For lwip_init
#include "lwip/tcpip.h" // For sys_check_timeouts
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include <stdio.h> // For printf

// Function to send a UDP message
void send_udp_message(struct udp_pcb *pcb) {
    struct pbuf *p;
    const char *message = "Hello, UDP!";

    // Create a pbuf to hold the message data
    p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, strlen(message), PBUF_RAM);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // Copy the message data into the pbuf payload
        memcpy(p->payload, message, strlen(message));

        // Send the pbuf over the UDP connection
        udp_send(pcb, p);

        // Free the pbuf
        pbuf_free(p);
    }
}

void simple_delay(uint32_t milliseconds) {
    volatile uint32_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < milliseconds; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4000; j++) {
            // Adjust the inner loop count based on your system's clock frequency
            __asm("nop");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct udp_pcb *pcb;

    // Initialize lwIP
    lwip_init();

    // Create a new UDP pcb
    pcb = udp_new();

    int i = 0;

    if (pcb != NULL) {
        // Bind the UDP pcb to a local port
        udp_bind(pcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 12345);

        // Set the remote IP address and port
        ip_addr_t remote_ip;
        IP4_ADDR(&remote_ip, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        udp_connect(pcb, &remote_ip, 54321);

        // Main loop
        while (1) {
            // Send the UDP message
            send_udp_message(pcb);

            // Main lwIP processing
            sys_check_timeouts();

            // Delay to control the rate of message sending
            simple_delay(1000);
            i++;
            printf("Cycle - %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I made some changes according to your response, but I still don't see any UDP message. Instead my microcontroller is sending this: "2   1.038562    fe80::1814:2da7:5472:f4e2   ff02::1:2   DHCPv6  148 Solicit XID: 0x62931f CID: 000100012d45818ac0b88323d67e "

```
//version2
#include "lwip/udp.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h> // For strlen
#include "lwip/init.h" // For lwip_init
#include "lwip/tcpip.h" // For sys_check_timeouts
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include "lwip/timers.h"
#include <stdio.h> // For printf

// Function to send a UDP message
void send_udp_message(struct udp_pcb *pcb) {
    struct pbuf *p;
    const char *message = "Hello, UDP!";

    // Create a pbuf to hold the message data
    p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, strlen(message)+1, PBUF_RAM);
    if (p != NULL) {
        // Copy the message data into the pbuf payload
        memcpy(p->payload, message, strlen(message)+1);

        // Send the pbuf over the UDP connection
        udp_send(pcb, p);

        // Free the pbuf
        pbuf_free(p);
    }
}

void simple_delay(uint32_t milliseconds) {
    volatile uint32_t i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < milliseconds; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4000; j++) {
            // Adjust the inner loop count based on your system's clock frequency
            __asm("");
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct udp_pcb *pcb;

    // Initialize lwIP
    lwip_init();

    // Create a new UDP pcb
    pcb = udp_new();

    int i = 0;

    if (pcb != NULL) {
        // Bind the UDP pcb to a local port
        udp_bind(pcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, 12345);

        // Set the remote IP address and port
        ip_addr_t remote_ip;
        IP4_ADDR(&remote_ip, 192, 168, 0, 87);
        udp_connect(pcb, &remote_ip, 54321);

        // Main loop
        while (1) {
            // Send the UDP message
            send_udp_message(pcb);

            // Main lwIP processing
            sys_check_timeouts();

            // Delay to control the rate of message sending
            simple_delay(1000);
            i++;
            printf("Cycle - %d\n", i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of thing that you should check here

1. Is `ping` working fine?
2. You have set remote ip address to `255.255.255.255`, which is the broadcast address. You are connected to a specific device and for that you should send the message to specific ip address instead.
3. Instead of using `strlen(message)` as length, use `strlen(message) + 1` to include the null terminator.
4. Check the firewall, if there is some blockage due to that.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I still don't see any UDP message on ethernet. I am editing my post to show the latest edit.